# spring dependency-management gradle plugin doesn't download dependency

Tags: spring, gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies, dependency-management

I'm using spring dependency-management gradle plugin on IntelliJ. I've a root module with following

```
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
      dependencySet(group: "org.apache.hadoop", version: "2.6.0-cdh5.14.4") {
                entry "hadoop-common"
                entry "hadoop-hdfs"
            }
     }
}
```

If I add

```
dependency 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-tools:2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.14.4'
```

or

```
dependencySet(group: "org.apache.hadoop", version: "2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.14.4") {
    entry ("hadoop-tools") {
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    }
}
```

in the root module, it doesn't download the `hadoop-tools` jar. It downloads this dependency only when I add the below in the sub module.

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "2.0.4"
}

dependencies {
    compile ("org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-tools:2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.14.4") {
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    }
}
```

Why is the behavior?

Comment: Hi. I have proposed an explanation in my answer, which is based on my understanding of your current script and what you tried to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @M.Ricciuti. This helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to understand this behavior you need to understand how Spring DependencyManagement plugin works (see  [this section](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/blob/master/README.md#dependency-management-dsl) in the official documentation ):

- the *dependencyManagement { }* block is used to configure the contraints that will apply to the dependencies (version to use, exclusions for transitive dependencies, etc..) but this block **will not** apply itself these dependencies to you project,
- the dependencies of your project must be configured using the *dependencies{ }* block

In your example:

- first you have configured the *dependencyManagement* block in root project with constraints on "hadoop-common" and "hadoop-hdfs" modules, then you added contraint on "hadoop-tools" (using "dependency" or "dependencySet" in the *dependencyManagement* block):  at this stage, you have not explicitly added any dependencies to your projects, but only configured the dependencies contraints

  ==>  this explains why "hadoop-tools" dependency is not added/downloaded to your project.
- then you added a "compile" dependency on "hadoop-tools" using the *dependencies* block
  , which is the correct way to declare dependencies, and this made the "hadoop-tools" lib available in your project.

If I understand well your requirement, based on the source code you provided in the question: you could configure your projects as follow:

**root project's script**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.4.RELEASE"
    }
}

// configure plugins to be applied and dependencies contraints for all subprojects
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin

    dependencyManagement {
        dependencies {
            // set version for hadoop-common & hadoop-hdfs to "2.6.0-cdh5.14.4"
            dependencySet(group: "org.apache.hadoop", version: "2.6.0-cdh5.14.4") {
                entry "hadoop-common"
                entry "hadoop-hdfs"
            }
            // set version "2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.14.4" for hadoop-tool, 
            //   and exclude slf4j-log4j12 module from transitive dependencies
            dependency (group: "org.apache.hadoop" , name: "hadoop-tools", version : "2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.14.4") {
                exclude 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12'
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url = 'https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/'
        }
    }
}
```

**sub-project script**

```
dependencies{

    // hadoop-tools module version is defined (constrained) 
    //   by dependencyManagement in root project build script
    compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-tools'

}
```